# How to update the value in key from array of objects?

Tags: ios, swift

How to update the value in key from array of objects?

I have an Array of objects. I need to change the value of one key. That means I need to change the `"quantity":"2","id":"1"`.
Before it was: `"quantity":"1","id":"1"`.

How to change?

In tableviewcell:

```
class ChartCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var delete:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemQuantityStepper:UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemQuantityLabel:UILabel?

    var quantity:Int {
        get {
            if (self.itemQuantityStepper != nil) {
                return Int(self.itemQuantityStepper!.value)
            }

            return 0
        }

        set {
            self.setItemQuantity(quantity)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    var cartadd : ((ChartCell) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func clickcartaddButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let value = Int(itemQuantityStepper!.value)
        setItemQuantity(value)

        cartadd?(self)
    }

    func setEventData(carts:CartModel)
    {
        self.name.text = carts.cartname
        self.price.text = carts.cartsum

        self.itemQuantityStepper.value = 1
    }

    func setItemQuantity(_ quantity: Int) {
        let itemQuantityText = "Qty. \(quantity)"
        itemQuantityLabel?.text = itemQuantityText

        itemQuantityStepper?.value = Double(quantity)
    }
}
```

I have firstly listed the data in the tableview. In tableviewcell I have used stepper. So while stepper action, the quantity increases.
I have quantity = 2. I need to pass this value in the model. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass this stepper value to the object of that array which you are loading to your tableview

get that object from array by following step.

set tag of your steeper button in cell as your indexpath.

suppose your model class is like 'myModel' class. than parse your data to this model and load the array to your table. now set your stepper button tag to your indexpath.row in your cellForRowAtIndexpath method. so when user clicks on stepper your slecter method ill be called where you can get your indexpath in sender.tag so you get the object from array.

hope this help!

```
class myModel : NSObject{
var name: String!
var price: String!
var quantity: String!
}

@IBAction func clickcartaddButton(sender: UIButton) {
 let value = Int(itemQuantityStepper!.value)
 setItemQuantity(value)
 let clickedObj = dummy_dataArray[sender.tag] as! myModel
 clickedObj.quantity = value
 cartadd?(self)
 }
```

Comment: dummy data is:[["name":"Fest","price":"QR 40","quantity":"3"],["name":" Vegan Fest","price":"QR 40","quantity":"1"]]  ,as when i click the stepper the quantity value become 2 that value i need to put in the dummydata,by giving as update how to give in that way